# How to implement softmax loss with variable length of choice

Tags: python, tensorflow, sequences

I'm trying to implement the drqa model on tensorflow where I'm going to predict begin and end position of the answer substring. So there is [batch_size, max_time] output of probabilities, corresponding context sequences. Now I want to apply softmax cross enthropy loss, but sequences are zero padded. So I don't want padding to be counted in loss. Is there some advice how to implement this? Thank you.

Comment: You need to add some code to show your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Use weights.

```
tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(
  labels,
  logits,
  weights=[1.]* actual_length + [0.]* (max_length - actual_length)
)
```